# Counterintuitive result on conditional expectation

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider three random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ and three dummy variables $D_1,D_2,D_3$ such that $D_1+D_2+D_3=1$.

Assume that
$$
E(X_j| D_1,D_2,D_3)=0 \quad \text{ for each $j=1,2,3$}
$$
**Claim:** $E(\sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j| D_1,D_2,D_3)=0$

**Proof of claim:**   We have that
$$
E(\sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j| D_1=1,D_2=0,D_3=0)=E(X_1|D_1=1,D_2=0,D_3=0)=0\\
E(\sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j| D_1=0,D_2=1,D_3=0)=E(X_2|D_1=0,D_2=1,D_3=0)=0\\
E(\sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j| D_1=0,D_2=0,D_3=1)=E(X_3|D_1=0,D_2=0,D_3=1)=0\\
$$
Hence, $E(\sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j| D_1,D_2,D_3)=0$.

**Corollary:** $E(D_k \sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j   )=0$ for each $k=1,2,3$.

**Proof of corollary:** Let $Z\equiv \sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j$. By the above claim,
$$
 E(Z| D_1,D_2,D_3)=0.
$$
Therefore, $E(Z D_k)=0$ for each $k=1,2,3$.

**Question:** I find the corollary result counterintuitive. In fact, it seems to claim that, e.g., the random variables $D_2$ and $\sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j$ are uncorrelated. However, $\sum_{j=1}^3 D_j X_j$ depends on $D_2$. Therefore, how can they be uncorrelated?

Comment: I haven't read everything carefully, but uncorrelatedness does not imply independence. Consider for instance $X \sim U([-1,1])$ and $Y=X^2$. You have that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, but they are clearly dependent.

Comment: What is the counterintuitiveness? I read everything you wrote very carefully and I didn't find a single result counterintuitive. Maybe your intuition is not fine tuned. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two zero-mean, finite-variance random variables. Uncorrelatedness of $X$ and $Y$ _signifies_ that they are _orthogonal_ in $\mathscr{L}^2.$ In other words, $(X, Y)$ is an orthogonal base of the 2-dimensionl vector space $\mathrm{span}(X,Y).$ We know from linear algebra that there are infinitely many orthogonal bases in a given 2-dimensional vector space. Every such base is function of both $X$ and $Y.$

Comment: @StratosFair in fact, if $X$ is any symmetric random variable (in $\mathscr{L}^3$), then $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated. _Sketch of proof:_ $EX^3 = EX = 0$ by symmetry.

Comment: To put things more clearly, I think, the correlation between two random variables is the _cosine of the angle between them._ Therefore, zero correlation means they are colinear, but that is it. Correlation and independence are as unrelated as it gets. I suspect the common confusion arises from the over-emphasis on the normal distribution whose joint-density is of the form $c e^{a(x)+b(y) + \rho c(x,y) },$ so the density factorises as a function of $x$ and of $y$ alone if and only if $\rho = 0$ ($\rho$ is the correlation). A similar result holds in higher dimensions.